# How to create IAIK keystore?

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, iaik-jce

I want to create an IAIK Keystore. I have iaik_jce_full signed jar. 
Also, i have full jurisdiction policy jar.

When I try to use keytool command in cmd prompt, it gives a null pointer exception at the last stage, after it had asked for all the details.

Please help!
If possible gives details because I have googled a lot and I am unable to resolve this issue. 
I have with me the certificates and the certificate chain which I want to put inside the IAIK keystore.

Comment: I have made an entry in java.security file.

Comment: Also, i have placed the iaik jar in ext folder in lib directory.